# Horizontally align images with captions below

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling to present two horizontally aligned images with text below. Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="selectGame">
  <div id="computerIcon" class = "icon">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com" >
    <span class ="iconText"><p>VS Computer</p></span>
  </div>
  <div id="humanIcon" class = "icon">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com" >
    <span class ="iconText"><p>VS Human</p></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.icon img{
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
}

.iconText p{
  clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right track and very close. For floating elements, be sure to also float the parent as well, in this case `div.icon`

```
.icon {
    float: left;
}
```

### [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/LsjLy0c8/)

Answer (score 0):

put the float:left and width: 40% on .icon class instead of .icon img - so

```
.icon {
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
}
```